# Broadcom driver issue with TP-Link Archer T6E AC1300 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I've just got a new PCI Express Wi-Fi adapter: [TP-Link Archer T6E AC1300](http://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5519_Archer-T6E.html).

```
$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

I have some problems with setting it up in Ubuntu 16.04.

<s>The problem is that this "dual band" device uses one of its bands to hotspot network with bssid TP-LINK_4DF618 (I can see it in Network Manager on the same computer and from other devices as well; it disappears when I turn the computer off).</s>

I don't know how to turn if off. (see UPD)

As a result the card works only with 2.4GHz networks. But the reason I've got this new adapter is 5GHz networks =(

I've already tried **bcmwl-kernel-source** and **broadcom-sta-dkms** drivers and even tried to install a driver from the Broadcom [website](https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search/?pf=Wireless%20LAN%20Infrastructure).

I would be grateful for any help.

**UPD:** Sorry, I misinterpreted results of my investigation. This mysterious network was from an other source that by coincidence appeared at the same time.

The source of my problems was in a settings of my router (Zyxel Keenetic Air). My router automatically assign some "optimal" channel for 5GHz network and apparently didn't work with this adapter. After I had chosen a channel manually everything started working well.

wireless-script.sh [output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24073615/)

Comment: The correct driver is `bcmwl-kernel-source`. Installing others does nothing at best and at worse it may be the source of conflicts. Now, I have no explanation for the phenomenon of *having a hotspot you didn't configured* (or did you?). This is a case for the experts, @chili555

Comment: Or also @Pilot6 ...

Comment: @CelticWarrior no, I didn't configured it. It kind of "build-in" setting of the device. I didn't find any evidence, that Ubuntu manages it. Even if I turn of wireless with modprobe -r wl this mystery network still remains. I think probably that it is possible to turn it off using windows software that comes with it, but I don't have any windows machine where I can check this.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks for your comments, I finally figured it out. That was lame =)

Comment: Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1574196

Comment: **Problem had nothing to do with Ubuntu.**

Comment: @chili555 thanks, this is exactly an issue I had.

Answer (score 1):

If the hotspot is the problem, remove it with

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

Reboot

Comment: The problem remains. This network is not managed by Ubuntu. It remains even if I do modprobe -r wl.

Comment: If you can do `sudo modprobe -r wl` and it still exists try `rfkill block wifi` if it exists after that, the source is not your computer

Comment: you are right. I misinterpreted results, clearly the source is not my computer.