# TP-Link AC1300 T6E PCI-E Wifi card not working

Tags: networking, wireless, tp-link

I am running the latest version of ubuntu (18.04.1) and the TP link T6E PCI-E wifi card is not working. I do not have the ability to run a wired connection to my computer. I have no idea where to even start I am just starting to learn linux.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the T9E. Fortunately, it is pretty simple if you have a smartphone that supports USB WiFi tethering. The reason for this is you must be able to establish some form of Internet connection to install the packages, and this was the easiest for me. Otherwise you will have to either get an Ethernet cable long enough to reach your router or move your PC close to it. You can find the full answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/905195).

It comes down to opening a terminal on your machine and running `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`, locating the package you need in the table shown in the answer I linked to, and doing `sudo apt install <PACKAGE>` where `<PACKAGE>` is your actual needed package.

For me this looked like `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`. There were instructions for an offline install, but this did not work for me even though I followed the instructions. You will need access to the internet on a device that you can move files from anyway.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your modifier `-d 14e4:` means that *only* Broadcom devices will be shown. Is the T6E a Broadcom?

Comment: [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887594/broadcom-driver-issue-with-tp-link-archer-t6e-ac1300-16-04) suggests that it is, and also points to the same package I ended up using

Answer (score 0):

wifi adapter not found?
Issue: Wifi driver is not installed. Mine was "rtl8821ce". Check the your "network controller" using `lspci` command.
then install the necessary driver, and you are good to go

P.S: sometimes `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` also solves the problem